# Operand ordering for matrix multiplication with assignment

Tags: api-design, interfaces, naming

If you have a matrix class with overloaded `operator*=`, which order should the operands be placed for the interface to be useful and intuitive. One can choose `A *= B` to be equivalent to either `A = A*B`, or `A = B*A`. From one point of view `A*=B` looks like it should do the first (this is how Octave implements it), but putting `B` to the left is more practical, since matrices are always stacked to the left. In particular if `A` is a column vector and `B` is a rotation matrix, then `A *= B` would accumulate rotations onto `A`, and the other convention would not even work.

Instead of using `operator*=`, one could also use names like `leftmul` and `rightmul`, but it is not obvious which one is which of these two options.

To add some context: The matrices are always 4 by 4 matrices, and vectors have four elements. The language I am using is C++.

Comment: You don't state what language you're writing this class in. It is worth reconsidering whether or not it is really appropriate to overload the operator at all. In general, A and B don't have to be square matrices and, if they are not square, then the result of matrix multiplication is a matrix with different dimensions than either the original A or original B. This is a problematic gotcha in a duck typed language and a deal breaker for a statically typed language.

Comment: @Matt In my case, the matrix will always be square 4 by 4 matrix. The vector type have four elements.

Comment: If your scope of use is narrow enough to stick with 4 by 4 then don't worry about  generalities. Use what works for you.

Comment: Given that `a -= b` is interpreted as ` a = a-b` (and likewise for `a/=b`) I'd be very reluctant to use `a *= b` to means `a = b*a`.  Some poor sap, in 12 or 18 months time, is going to spend fruitless hours figuring out that non-conformity.  Usually the poor sap is the person who wrote the code in the first place.

Comment: @Matt: Your comment really needs to be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reconsidering whether or not it is really appropriate to overload this operator. Generally, in mathematics, A and B don't have to be square matrices and, if they are not square, then the result of matrix multiplication is a matrix with different dimensions than either the original A or original B. This is a problematic gotcha in a duck typed language and a deal breaker for a statically typed language.

Although your intent is to only support 4 by 4 matrices and length 4 vectors now, it is still worth considering future extensibility of the class. The general case is also worth considering from the perspective of the expectations of users of your API. It should be obvious to any new user of your API who has prior experience with matrix algebra what the intended meaning of the overloaded operator is. Since it's not obvious, in my opinion, it is better not to overload the operator.

Comment: Typically, implementations of mathematical matrixes as classes don't consider matrixes of different dimensions to be of different types. Like vectors or lists, the dimensions of a matrix are usually an attribute or property of the object. Instead of having an infinite number of types, you have code in the various operations that checks the dimensions of the operands, and confirms that the operation is legal. The second part of your answer about consistency with prior notation is much more on the mark.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Even without considering matrices of different dimensions to be different types, it can still be problematic if the class treats the matrix size as immutable once it is declared.

Comment: @Matt Given that multiplication in-place makes sense, do you have an alternative name for the operation?

Comment: @Matt "it can still be problematic if the class treats the matrix size as immutable once it is declared." Some context might be useful here. The matrix classes I've been exposed to have mostly been for floating point number crunching, and the primary matrix classes have always been mutable, for reasons of efficiency. An immutable matrix type might also be provided, but it's not the main tool.